# Connect Android Wearable Emulator with Handheld device which is connected to adb WIRELESSLY

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-emulator, wear-os

Is it possible to connect wearable emulator to handheld device which is connected to adb wirelessly ?

1) First I connected my phone to adb wirelessly with the adb tcpip 5555 command. 
2) Now, my phone is connected with adb by ip address assigned to it in local wlan. (adb connect ipaddress) 
3) Now I started my emulator of wearable device and I want to connect that to that handheld device connected wirelessly. For normal connection, command for this is adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601 but I know that this obviously won't work here.

So my question here is : Is it possible to achieve this? 
Whether it's a yes or no, can you explain me why ? I don't have much idea about tcp ports etc. I tried to google it but could not find much information about it online. So, it would be great if you can explain me about this.

It is written in adb help that forward command would forward the port depending on what you specify. So I also want to know about the exact detailing for this and how it works.

I don't have any command over networking concepts so please explain accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to specify the remote device?
Something like this: adb -s {remote_device_ip}:5555 -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
And then on the Android device to choose "Connect to the emulator"?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the command to pair to device like this

```
adb -s <remote_device_ip>:5555 -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

Example in my case:

```
adb -s 192.168.0.7:5555 -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```